# Extended splash screen in PhoneGap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

What I need to do is to implement extended splash screen. I have two different images that I need to show. The first one I set to be application splash screen, but as I need to show it for a bit longer than the usual splash screen would be visible I was thinking to set the same image as a background of index.html page (as index.html page is the first visible page) and after that to navigate (lets say after 3-4 seconds) to page splash2.html and to set the second image as a background of this page. My question is, is there some better practice (I am new to PhoneGap)? And do I need to have these images in all different resolutions that I have a splash screen in. Does someone did something similar? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Splash 1 (App/System Splash)

You can config your app to keep showing the splash screen until you manually remove it.

Add this to you config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="yourSplashScreenFileName.xyz" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

And this to your JavaScript, whenever you want to remove it:

```js
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

Take a look at the [official splashscreen plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.splashscreen) for further information.

### Splash 2

To show the second splash, add an element with width and height of 100% to your body and set a background image (and `background-size: contain`). That way you only need one high res image. Depending on the content of yours splashes, `background-size: cover` might be a better fit for you. Just give it a try.

To remove the second splash, just remove this element from the DOM.

Comment: And what to do with the second image I need to show as a splash screen? I have 2 splash screens.

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer.